# NodeJS os module unable to use userInfo()

Tags: node.js

https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_userinfo_options

Node Version: v4.2.6
NPM Version: 3.5.2

When attempting to use the os module to pull username information from the system, I am receiving the error: TypeError: os.userInfo is not a function

Here is my syntax:

```
console.log('Starting Application');

const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');

var user = os.userInfo();

fs.appendFile('greetings.txt', 'Hello  ' + user.username + '!');
```

Comment: Added in: v6.0.0

Answer (score 4):

os.userInfo([options]) added in  `v6.0.0` you can use following ponyfill

[Node.js os.userInfo() ponyfill](https://github.com/sindresorhus/user-info)

USAGE

```
$ npm install --save user-info



const userInfo = require('user-info');

console.log(userInfo());
/*
{
    uid: 501,
    gid: 20,
    username: 'sindresorhus',
    homedir: '/Users/sindresorhus',
    shell: '/bin/zsh'
}
*/
```