# Node.js's "os" module does not have the userInfo() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to use the ["os" module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os) from node.js, to amongst other things, use  the userInfo() method. But the method does not seem to exist, even though the [API specification](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) clearly states that it does.

Specifically, I get the type error "os.userinfo is not a function" when I try to use a file that is using that method. If I for example try to import the following simple file

```
const os = require('os');
const user = os.userInfo();
```

I get the error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: os.userInfo is not a function
```

And this is obvious if I try to console log the os module, since this doesn't show any userInfo method, but it should?

The code is being run in a React SPA, using docker, which is running the node version 11.12.0.

Also, if any help, I am trying to implement something like [this](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-electron-applications-with-openid-connect-and-oauth-2/).

Second edit: My question is being marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846222/nodejs-os-module-unable-to-use-userinfo), but this is not the case. That users error was caused by using an old (<6.00) version of node, and the top answer uses a deprecated node module.

Comment: Can you post the error message that shows up?  I just ran it locally on my machine and it seems to work just fine (V 10.15.3).

Comment: You should show the error message you got

Comment: Could it be that your casing is off, i.e. you are trying to call `userinfo` when it's `userInfo` (the error message does not match your code example)

Comment: I'll edit OP with the exact error message. And it is not a case issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS os module unable to use userInfo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846222/nodejs-os-module-unable-to-use-userinfo)

Comment: I read that one Jacob Nelson, and it seems that the problem there was an old (< 6.00) node version.

Comment: @RichardJensen Please add whatever details you added to that deleted question. Also can you try out the function in node shell and post the reply below.

Comment: @PrivateOmega It is done.

Comment: @RichardJensen Could you post reply after running the command sequence in node shell. I got a reply `{ uid: -1,
  gid: -1,
  username: 'MohanKiranMathew',
  homedir: 'C:\\Users\\MohanKiranMathew',
  shell: null }` in my windows PC.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. It works! So I guess it has something to do with me running the program in a docker container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my last answer was deleted (presumably because I asked a rhetorical question), I'll clarify:

You mentioned that:

> the code is being run in a React SPA, using docker, which is running the
>   node.....

If you're trying to call `os.userInfo()` from client-side (React) code, you can't do that with Javascript running in a browser, it would be a security flaw. That method only exists in NodeJS (which has a special wrapper around V8 for general interaction with the OS such as *fs* module etc).

You can only call the function from a **NodeJS server**. Getting the userInfo in Electron (as you mentioned in your comment to my answer) should be relatively straightforward through the above-mentioned function or `process.env['USER'];` for UNIX-based systems, as Electron is built with NodeJS.

Comment: Weird, since I marked your answer as solving my question. Anyway, this is exactly my problem, so now I know what to do (and that my original approach was fundamentally flawed).